# Method Not Allowed when posting requesting using nodemailer strapi

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, strapi

so far I have been able to establish Test email delivery on strapi but I am not having any luck with posting a request when I am using the postman. For example I created route

```html
// api/email/config/routes.json
{
    "routes": [
      {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/emails",
        "handler": "Email.send",
        "config": {
            "policies": []
          }
      }
    ]
  }
```

and then rest of the email body here is an example:

```html
// File /api/email/controllers/Email.js
'use strict'

/**
 * Read the documentation () to implement custom controller functions
 */

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Sends an email to the recipient in the body of the request
   */
  send: async (ctx) => {
    const body = ctx.request.body
    const sendTo = body.email
    strapi.log.debug(`Trying to send an email to ${sendTo}`)

    try {
      const emailOptions = {
        to: sendTo,
        subject: 'This is a test',
        html: `<h1>Welcome!</h1><p>This is a test HTML email.</p>`,
      }
      await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send(emailOptions)
      strapi.log.debug(`Email sent to ${sendTo}`)
      ctx.send({ message: 'Email sent' })
    } catch (err) {
      strapi.log.error(`Error sending email to ${sendTo}`, err)
      ctx.send({ error: 'Error sending email' })
      console.log('====================================');
      console.log(err);
      console.log('====================================');
    }
  },
}
```

after running the application I posted request http://localhost:1337/emails and tried sending this json body {"email": "validemail@gmail.com"} but I keep receiving `Method Not Allowed` I can't seem to find what did I do wrong. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you change the path  "path": "/emails", to "path": "/emails/custom/send", or "emails/send" i am not sure i think strapi url may conflict with other

Comment: Hi @MaheshKS I tried using both paths still no luck so far. I attached the output from my postman request

Comment: Update I found the mistake, the reason it didn't work because I had to run ` npm run strapi generate`  and create a api service for me to post instead of creating folders.